# How to display all possible enum values in a dropdown list using Spring and Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a domain object that has an enum property and I want to display a dropdown list with all possible enum values in the form for this object. Imagine the following object:

```
public class Ticket {

  private Long id;

  private String title;

  private State state;

  // Getters & setters

  public static enum State {
    OPEN, IN_WORK, FINISHED
  }

}
```

In my controller I have a method that renders a form for this object:

```
@RequestMapping("/tickets/new")
public String showNewTicketForm(@ModelAttribute Ticket ticket) {
  return "tickets/new";
}
```

The template looks like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/tickets}" method="post" th:object="${ticket}">
  <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" />
  <select></select>
</form>
```

Later it should be transformed to something like this:

```
<form action="/tickets" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <select name="state">
    <option>OPEN</option>
    <option>IN_WORK</option>
    <option>FINISHED</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

How can I create the select tag? The selected value should also be mapped to the ticket automatically so that I can do something like this in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tickets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createTicket(@Valid Ticket ticket) {
  service.createTicket(ticket);

  return "redirect:/tickets";
}
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You could do:

```html
<select>
    <option th:each="state : ${T(com.mypackage.Ticket.State).values()}"
            th:value="${state}"
            th:text="${state}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the T?

Comment: Its the spring EL syntax for accessing a type and invoking static methods or getting static properties in it. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types

Comment: On `th:value=${{state}}` use the conversion tags

Comment: it giving me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Iteration variable cannot be null

Comment: This solution helped me a lot, thanks!
I actually using it to set src and tooltip for list of images. It might be helpful for someone:

<img th:each="ds : ${T(com.mypackage.enum.DataStoreType).values()}" th:src="${ds.iconName}" th:title="${ds.typeName}" th:data-dsname="${{ds}}" data-toggle="tooltip">

I have added final String fields to the enums and added the proper getters and constructor.

Answer (score 27):

In addition, if you want to separate the enum ordinal name from the string displayed in the GUI, add additional properties, for example a *displayName*:

```
public static enum State {

    OPEN("open"),
    IN_WORK("in work"),
    FINISHED("finished");

    private final String displayName;

    State(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

And in the html file:

```
<select>
  <option th:each="state : ${T(com.mypackage.Ticket.State).values()}" th:value="${state}" th:text="${state.displayName}"></option>
</select>
```

This will present the *displayName* to the user and allows you to silently change this strings later without refactoring the code. You may add more properties like *th:title* this way.

Comment: How could we achieve the same result by overriding toString, or we can't?

Comment: @atas yes you can override toString()

Comment: @Clint `"${state}"` calls toString() by default, so overriding toString() didn't help. I tried to use `th:value="${state.name}"` but I get a parsing error

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

Java:

```
public enum RoleEnum {
    SUPER_ADMIN("SUPER_ADMIN"),
    RESTAURANTE_ADMIN("RESTAURANTE_ADMIN");

    private final String roleCode;

    private RoleEnum(String roleCode) {
        this.roleCode = roleCode;
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<select class="form-control" id="val-skill" name="role_id">
    <option th:each="role : ${T(com.users.enumeration.RoleEnum).values()}" th:value="${role}" th:text="${role}"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

for performance it is better to store the enums value in a field of the controller and send it as a model attribute because every call to enum.values generate a new copy of the values array. depending on the size on the enum this can represent some work repeted.