# Spring Security how to set roles for user while user registration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, registration, roles

currently I'm working on a Spring Boot based web application in Java. I'm trying to create worker registration for my application. To be honest this is my first application like this and I don't really know how to grant user roles while registration. I've watched a couple of tutorials, but no one shows how to grant roles, while adding new user to database.

In my database I have tables Worker and Role like below.

In registration form I have two checkboxes: worker and admin and I would like to grant permissions depending on which ones have been selected .

This is what I have:

**Worker.java**

```
@Id
@Column(name = "workerId")
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "native",
        strategy = "native"
)
private int workerId;

@Column(name = "login")
@NotEmpty
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
@NotEmpty
private String password;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "workerId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Role> roles;
```

**WorkerRole.java**

```
public enum WorkerRole {
WORKER,ADMIN;}
```

**Role.java**

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "workerId")
private Worker workerId;

@Id
@Column(name = "role")
private String role;

//getters and setters
```

**WorkerService.java**

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private WorkerRepository workerRepository;

@Autowired
public WorkerService(WorkerRepository workerRepository){
    this.workerRepository = workerRepository;
}

public Worker findByEmail(String email){
    return workerRepository.findByEmail(email);
}

public Optional<Worker> findByUsername(String username)
{
    return workerRepository.findByUsername(username);
}

public Worker findByConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken){
    return workerRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
}

public void saveUser(Worker worker){
    workerRepository.save(worker);
}

public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return charSequence.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return true;
        }
    };
}

public Worker findByUname(String login){
    Worker worker = null;
    try{
        worker = entityManager.createQuery("select w from Worker w " +
                "where w.login = :login ", Worker.class)
                .setParameter("login", login)
                .getSingleResult();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("No results found for that uname");
    }

    return worker;
}
```

**CustomUserDetails.java**

```
public CustomUserDetails(final Worker worker) {
    super(worker);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return getRoles()
            .stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return super.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return super.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Autowired
private WorkerRepository workerRepository;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<Worker> optionalUsers = workerRepository.findByUsername(username);

    optionalUsers
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Worker not found"));
    return optionalUsers
            .map(CustomUserDetails::new)
            .get();
}
```

I think that's all, I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: This modelling looks wrong to me. Workers can have multiple roles (@OneToMany) while a Role can only accommodate a single worker (@ManyToOne)?.

Answer (score 1):

In case of yours, you don't need that `Role` class. Just use `List<WorkerRole> roles` in `Worker.java`.
Also you can implement `UserDetails` in `Worker.java`, instead of using that `CustomUserDetails`.

Assuming that you are using Thymeleaf, a multiple selection dropdown [can be populated with enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29515536/9213632).

After populating dropdown with enum values, you can just select role(s) and create the new user.