# Thymeleaf Dropdown Menu

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a dropdown list in my form.  My user entered text inputs are showing up, however, my dropdown for the enum is not listing the values.  I know there are other posts on here about the same topic (which I've read) but still can't seem to get the dropdown to show up.  Can someone help me?  This is what I have tried...

```
            <form action="#" th:action="@{${isAdded}?'/save':'/update'}" th:object="${user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                Dropdown for User type or role
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <select th:field="*{type}">
                        <option
                                th:each="type : ${UserType.values()}"
                                th:value="${type}"
                                th:text="${type}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text", class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{firstName}">
                </div>
.... The remaining text inputs have been omitted...
```

I've also tried based on this [StackOverflow Post...How to display all possible enum values in a dropdown list using Spring and Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515366/how-to-display-all-possible-enum-values-in-a-dropdown-list-using-spring-and-thym)

```
 <div class="form-group" >
                    <select th:field="*{type}">
                        <option
                                th:each="type : ${T(com.abbyhowe.LearnFolio.models.User.type).values()}"
                                th:value="${type}"
                                th:text="${type}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

This made the dropdown show up but didn't show the list of types as selectable options.

```
<div class="form-group" >
                    <select th:field="*{type}">
                        <option
                                th:each="type : ${types}"
                                th:value="${type}"
                                th:text="${type}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Here is my User class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /***
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8885466378515990394L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "First name is required")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Name must be between 3 and 50 characters")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private UserType type;
```

Here is my enum UserType...

```
public enum UserType {
    TEACHER("Teacher"),
    STUDENT("Student"),
    ADMIN("Account Administrator");

    private final String displayName;

    UserType(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work.  I'll add what I tried just in the above code samples.

Comment: OK - understood. Could you help to clarify "it didn't work"? What HTML is rendered? Are there any error messages?

Comment: First, thank you for trying to help.  In the third bit of HTML above,  I can get the dropdown to show up but it does not have any values in the dropdown list.  I'm wondering if the th:value or th:text values are coded incorrectly?  At this point, I don't get any error messages which has made it difficult to troubleshoot.  @andrewjames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
 <form action="#" th:action="@{${isAdd}?'/save':'/update'}" th:object="${user}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!--                Dropdown for User type or role-->
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <select th:field="*{type}">
                        <option
                                th:each="type : ${T(com.abbyhowe.LearnFolio.models.UserType).values()}"
                                th:value="${type}"
                                th:text="${type.displayName}">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```